# Help on Elo System specifics for large group competitions

Tags: algorithm, ranking

I'm trying to implement an Elo-based ranking system for the sport my website deals with.

There's a few thousand competitors, and each competition sees anything from 50 to 500 of them go against the clock.  Fastest man wins.

My initial thought was that a race with 50 people can be treated as 50*49/2 = 1225 one-on-one matches.

I do all of these comparisons in one go, and adjust each competitors rating at the end.  I.e. if someone's rating is 1600 it remains that for all 49 comparisons I make, and is adjusted by the sum of all the changes at the end.  This doesn't seem right... is this what I should be doing?

The problem I have is that if one (normally strong) competitor has a terrible day (e.g. injury) then he can suddenly be beaten by 40+ people that he would normally beat.  They all have lower ratings than him, and as such his rating gets PUMMELLED.  With the recommended K-factor of 32 I see swings of thousands of points in a single event...  If I drastically reduce the K factor (say, to 1) things are better, but I feel this is flawed.

Instead of summing all of the adjustments, should I be averaging them in some way?  Or taking the most extreme value?  Got my head in a bit of a twist here!

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I think that it is a bad idea to use ELO here.

Comment: @svante - I'm fine with that! Care to give any feedback on what I SHOULD be using?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than treating a race of 50 as 1225 one-on-one matches I think you would get better results by treating it as 50 one-on-one matches where it's player vs. max(everybody else). Unless there's a reason racing against 10 opponents is any more difficult than racing against the best of those 10 opponents in a winner-takes-all scenario?

Comment: But with Elo you rank the winner up, and the loser down.  Matching everyone against the winner means the winner's rank would be bumped up 50 times, while each of the losers would only see their rank reduced once.  The guy who wins will SOAR up the rankings, while 2nd place downwards will see only small changes?

Comment: Right, so for 50 players each one is ranked either up or down based on their score vs max(everyone else). The winner as well as each loser is only bumped once after each race.

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't occur to me that you could score the winner against 2nd place. I will give that a go and see how it pans out. I think I'm going to end up using TrueSkill anyway, but it'd be good to get elo working first just to get a feel for it, and I suspect I'd have had a very similar issue in TrueSkill. I'm HOPING there will be no need to "weed out" the worst results. It's not uncommon for someone to win 90% of competitions, and barely even finish in the other 10%... hopefully the algo won't give too much weight to those negative blips?

Comment: Not 2nd place, your highest ranked opponent. I was assuming everyone who doesn't win loses since you said the fastest man wins. If that's not the case you may consider awarding points based on finish position.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the underlying math behind Elo.  The idea behind Elo is to assume that every player has a given "play strength" represented by a normally-distributed (or, I believe as it's now used, logistically-distributed) random variable, then to try to estimate that variable.  Elo is set up so that someone with an Elo rating 200 points higher than another player should have an expected outcome of .75 in a game (where 1 means "win", 0.5 is "draw", and 0 is "loss.")  The Elo calculation is designed so that it adjusts the hidden variable based on observable behavior about how the player performed against another player.

Given that you are having a multi-way tournament, it seems that the parameter estimation model would be different.  I am not a mathematician or a statistician, but it seems like there must be some way to do parameter estimation from a multi-way tournament just as it could be done from a one-on-one tournament.  This approach seems theoretically ideal, though regrettably I don't have anything concrete to suggest along these lines.